# Can't get Docker outside of Docker to work with Jenkins in ECS

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to get the Jenkins Docker image deployed to ECS and have docker-compose work inside of my pipeline.

I have hit wall after wall trying to get this Jenkins container launched and functioning. Most of the issues have just been getting the docker command to work inside of a pipeline (including getting the permissions/group right).

I've gotten to the point that the command works and uses the host docker socket (`docker ps` outputs the jenkins container and ecs agent) and docker-compose is working (`docker-compose --version` works) but when I try to run anything that involves files inside the pipeline, I get a "no such file or directory" error. This happens when I run docker-compose -f docker-compose.testing.yml up -d --build (it can't find the yml file) and also when I try to run a basic docker build, it can't find local files used in the COPY command (ie. COPY . /app). I've tried from changing the command to be ./file.yml and $PWD/file.yml and still getting the same error.

Here is my Jenkins Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl

RUN apt-get remove docker
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

RUN curl -L --fail https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN groupadd -g 497 dockerami \
  && usermod -aG dockerami jenkins

USER jenkins

COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

COPY jobs /app/jenkins/jobs

COPY jenkins.yml /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.yml

RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

RUN echo 2.0 > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state

ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.yml
```

I also have Terraform building the task definition and binding the /var/run/docker.sock from the host to the jenkins container.

I'm hoping to get this working since I have liked Jenkins since we started using it about 2 years ago and I've had these pipelines working with docker-compose in our non-containerized Jenkins install, but getting Jenkins containerized so far has been pulling teeth. I would much prefer to get this working than to have to change my workflows right now to something like Concourse or Drone.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that you have in your Dockerfile is that you are copying a file into `/var/jenkins_home` which will disappear as `/var/jenkins_home` is defined as a volume in the parent Jenkins image and any files you copy into a volume ***after*** the volume has been declared are discarded - see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes